# can we only use DPDK queue without using other dpdk features in c++ application

Tags: multithreading, dpdk

I have a existing c++ application(Linux) which uses our own implementation of Queue. 
Here a thread "Thread1" reads from the NIC interface and writes to a Queue and another thread "Thread2" dequeue from the Queue. 
It has been implemented by using a lock mechanism. To make enqueue/dequeue faster I wanted to implement only DPDK queue in my application. I did a POC and could find that the performance improves.

The challenge I face is that as soon as I initialize my code with "rte_eal_init" all of the CPU cores are taken under control of DPDK threads(if I pass 1 core using command line argument, then only that core is take ). I want to avoid the taking of cores by DPDK. I simply want to use DPDK Queue as any other library.

Another challenge is that if i do not use the DPDK API to spin the threads, then all of the threads spawn after "rte_eal_init" spawns on the master CPU (cpu0). I am expecting the threads to be scheduled by scheduler freely in any of the cores.

Can someone provide any idea if it is possible to do, or there is any other way to get this done.

Comment: Please format your question (line breaks where appropriate, etc)

Comment: Done formatting

Answer (score 0):

Dpdk rte_eal_init does not consume 100% of the master cpu. Its just a config function to initialize the dpdk components. It is rx_burst when run in poll mode (continuous loop) which causes 100% utilization.

If the goal is use dpdk ring buffers and libraries, you can do the same

1. Instead of continuous poll by either master or worker thread, try using interrupt mode.
2. One can also use AF_XDP SOCK to fetch packets with select too.

Once you acquire the packet, as per your requirement you are putting it into an intermediate ring buffer. Using the second thread you are deque from ring too. This will cause thread-2 to go into polling.

With regard to threads wait, run and stop states please go through l2fwd, or skeleton. There are API like remote_launch wait in the dpdk API list which does the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Another challenge is that if i do not use the DPDK API to spin the threads, then all of the threads spawn after "rte_eal_init" spawns on the master CPU (cpu0). I am expecting the threads to be scheduled by scheduler freely in any of the cores.

you can use `pthread_setaffinity_np` to recover cpu

```
    cpu_set_t cpuSet;
    pthread_getaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuSet);
    auto ret = rte_eal_init(...);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuSet);
```